# Resizing images in the Modelica documentation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Consider this scenario. I save a plotted curve using the save option in OMEdit Plotting Window. I want to use this image in the Documentation of the same model as a reference for others. But the issue with this is the images that are saved using this feature are very big and take up a lot of space(i.e. width and height) in the Documentation window.

I tried using the HTML code `width = "xx" height = "yy"`. But this did not work.

Is there any way I can resize the images using HTML code in the OpenModelica Documentation?

Comment: Could you post the full annotation string you are using? It is working fine for me using `Documentation(info = "<html><img width=\"200\" src=\"something.png\" /><img width=\"40\" src=\"something.png\" /></html>")`

Comment: Thanks. That works sjoelund. I was using this format of HTML image resizing which didnt work.

<img src=\"smiley.png\" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for information. The size of the exported plot image depends on the size of the plot window. The plot window is a MDI container so you can resize the plot window and then can export a smaller image.

The following code works fine for me (uses the same Documentation annotation as suggested by Martin),

```
model documentation
  annotation(Documentation(info = "<html>
  <img width=\"200\" src=\"modelica://documentation/modeling.png\" />
  <br />
  <img width=\"100\" src=\"modelica://documentation/modeling.png\" />
  </html>"));
end documentation;
```

Here is the sample screenshot, [image]

Comment: Yes Adeel, the code given by Martin works. I was using this version of HTML image resizing which did not work. <img src=\"smiley.png\" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">. But your suggestion about resizing the plot window and exporting the image is a better and faster option.